# How to render the Markdown code or HTML code in the "descripting" property for vscode snippets

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions

I want to write an extension for Visual Studio Code.I know this needs by code snippets or intellisense.

I read the official documents: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets.Code snippets can resolve my most demand.I hava a snippets like this:

```json
"tag": {
  "prefix": "vtag.text",
  "body": [
    "{% ${1|u,emp,wavy,del,kbd,psw|}${TM_SELECTED_TEXT} $0 %}"
  ],
  "description": [
    "text标签: \n",
    "带 {% u 下划线 %} 的文本", 
    "带 {% emp 着重号 %} 的文本",
    "带 {% wavy 波浪线 %} 的文本",
    "带 {% del 删除线 %} 的文本",
    "键盘样式的文本：{% kbd ⌘ %}",
    "密码样式的文本：{% psw 这里没有验证码 %}"
  ]
}
```

It will appear like this:
[image]

But on this hover window, it can only be filled with text, that corresponds to the property "description".
I want to show something else, like link(<a href="xxx"></a>), like some stylized text, like other markdown pattern or html pattern.I don't know how to work on code snippets.

I konw there are some other ways to show the hover window.The following is a simple example:

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  /** 支持的语言类型 */
  const LANGUAGES = [
    "markdown"
  ];
  const dictionary = ["htag", "vtag"];
  const triggers = [" "];
  const completionProvider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(
    LANGUAGES, 
    {
      async provideCompletionItems(
        document: vscode.TextDocument,
        position: vscode.Position,
        token: vscode.CancellationToken,
        context: vscode.CompletionContext
      ) {
        const range = new vscode.Range(
          new vscode.Position(position.line, 0),
          position
        );
        const text: string = document.getText(range);
        let completionItemList: vscode.CompletionItem[] = dictionary.filter((item) => item.tag.startsWith(text)).map((item, idx) => ({
          label: item.tag,
          preselect: idx === 0,
          documentation: new vscode.MarkdownString('<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul>'),  // Just an example
          sortText: `my_completion_${idx}`, 
        }));
        return completionItemList
      }
    }, 
    ...triggers
  );
  context.subscriptions.push(completionProvider)

}

// This method is called when your extension is deactivated
export function deactivate() {}
```

And I'can also registering hover window by api `vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider`

```js
const vscode = require('vscode');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider('javascript', {
  provideHover(document, position, token) {
    const fileName    = document.fileName;
    const workDir     = path.dirname(fileName);
    const word        = document.getText(document.getWordRangeAtPosition(position));
    console.log(1, document)
    console.log(2, position)
    console.log(3, token)
    console.log(4, '这个就是悬停的文字', word)
    // 支持markdown语法
    return new vscode.Hover(
    `### 我就是返回的信息!
      1. 第一项：
        - 第一个元素
        - 第二个元素
      2. 第二项：
        - 第一个元素
        - 第二个元素
  `);
  }
 }
);
```

So let me come back to my question.How do I add complexity to my code snippet description.Not only simple text.

Thank you!

Comment: A snippet description can only render simple text, not a markdown string.  The description is intended to provide very basic information and isn't very fancy.